# Drop rows that have same values as column names in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want drop rows that have same values as column names in Pandas.
I was thinking about making an nested array of my dataframe and looping trough that array and checking if nested array is the same as my df.columns. But maybe there is some faster way?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColA":[1,3,"ColA",1],
                   "ColB":[5,1,"ColB",2],
                   "ColC":[1,5,"ColC",2]})

print(df)

   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     5     1
1     3     1     5
2  ColA  ColB  ColC
3     1     2     2
```

And my result should look like:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC
0     1     5     1
1     3     1     5
3     1     2     2
```

Row 2 should be removed

Comment: I have to ask, why does your data look like this?

Comment: web scrapping tables from wikipedia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `eq` , with `any` (any cell contain columns name ) or `all` (all cell for each contain the columns name)

```
df[~df.eq(df.columns).any(1)]
  ColA ColB ColC
0    1    5    1
1    3    1    5
3    1    2    2
```

Comment: Or `df[df.ne([*df]).all(1)]`

Comment: @Yoben_S, could you please explain the use of the *~*? I have not seen that used before in python.

Comment: @JeffGruenbaum ~True= False :-)